# Javascript regex with negative lookbehind (review)

Tags: javascript, regex

I was hoping someone could review my regular expression to make sure that it's doing what I want it to do.

So here's what I'm after:

1. Search for a word within a word boundary - so it can be a word on its own, or a word within another word
2. Grab the preceding 30 characters (if preceding characters exist), but only if they *do not* contain the word I am searching for.
3. Grab the next 30 characters (if they exist)

So if I were searching for "car" for 1, I have:

```
(\b\w*car\w*\b)
```

For 2, I have:

```
((?!\b\w*car\w*\b).{30}|.{0,30})
```

For 3, I have:

```
.{0,30}
```

All together:

```
((?!\b\w*car\w*\b).{30}|.{0,30})(\b\w*car\w*\b).{0,30}
```

Have I got it right, will this do what I'm after?

Comment: this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question

Comment: Can you add some examples of valid and invalid strings for this expression?

Comment: Run this in a the console and check if the output is what you want/expect: `"I'm an psychodelic purple and green electric smartcar that goes insanely really fast and can lap the Earth on a single charge".match(/((?!\b\w*car\w*\b).{30}|.{0,30})(\b\w*car\w*\b)(.{0,30})/)`

Comment: *Have I got it right, will this do what I'm after?* I don't know, does it?

Comment: Almost, slight change was required

Comment: This appears to be an attempt at a workaround to JavaScript's lack of lookbehind support.  In that light, perhaps you'd like to read more about [how to properly implement lookbehind in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight change that needed to be made to your regex.

The last `.{0, 30}` needs to be put into a group.  The full regex is then becomes this:

```
/((?!\b\w*car\w*\b).{30}|.{0,30})(\b\w*car\w*\b)(.{0,30})/
```

If you run this in a javascript console you can see the output:

```
var str = "I'm an psychodelic purple and green electric smartcar that goes insanely really fast and can lap the Earth on a single charge"
var match = str.match(/((?!\b\w*car\w*\b).{30}|.{0,30})(\b\w*car\w*\b)(.{0,30})/);

alert(
  "Word containing car: " + match[2] +
  "\nFirst 30: " + match[1] +
  "\nLast 30: " + match[3]
);
```

You should get the following alert message:

```
Word containing car: smartcar
First 30: lic purple and green electric 
Last 30:  that goes insanely really fas
```