# Regex that matches all spaces except?

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex that matches all spaces but:

1. `\sand\s`
2. `\sor\s`
3. `\sbut\s`
4. `,\s`

**Input**

font weight, width and height, background, or background color, but transform style

`input.replace(regex,"-")`

**Matches**

fontweight, width and height, background, or backgroundcolor, but transformstyle

**Replace**

font`-`weight, width and height, background, or background`-`color, but transform`-`style
 
 
 
**Output**

font-weight, width and height, background, or background-color, but transform-style

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't support negative lookbehind, so this could be quite difficult. One quick thing to note: `\s` is not regex for "space". It's a character set that includes all whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, carriage return, form feed, and vertical tab). You could get unexpected behavior if you use `\s` when you only want to match ` `.

Comment: `\t` `\n` `\r` have already been removed… so the only thing left are spaces.

Comment: Sure, but you can still just use a literal space. That's what you're trying to match, right? At the very least you'll save space because you're using one character instead of two.

Comment: I just used `\s` to show space in question… otherwise it won't show up.

Comment: `@CAustin`s comment about the `\s` is irrelevant if your outputting to HTML, since one or more white spaces and/or line breaks is just a single space in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't support look behinds, you won't find a regex which will be able to do it as simply as the replace as you have there.  If you are willing to extend the replace logic a bit, you can use an answer such as the following (adapted from answer here: [Regex negative lookbehind not valid in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript/35143111#35143111))

```js
var input = " font weight, bland food, width and height, background, or background color, but transform style, and background repeat"
var regex = /\b(\s?and|\s?but|\s?or|,)?\s/g
var output = input.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
   return ($1 ? $0 : "-")
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Why you use `\sand` but not `\sor` and `\sbut`? Try also to better format your *blocks* `{}`

Comment: There is one bug in the code… this string won't work ` font weight, or height, box shadow`

Comment: There is a space at the beginning of the string

Comment: Thanks for both bug reports.  Edit fixes both.  Also added "bland food" as an example of where not being careful with the boundary could have caused a problem.