# Negative lookbehind for all `{{` not preceded by `<em>`

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string such as

```
The quick brown {{ fox }} jumped over the lazy <em>{{ dog }}</em>
```

I'm looking for a pattern that will match all instances of `{{` *not* preceded by the `<em>` block

Whilst the pattern `/(?<!>)\{{2}/gm` will work, this is not an option for Firefox and IE flavours of JS.

I’ve done a fair bit of digging and can find a great deal of examples that almost get there but not quite. Getting a positive match for the string `_>{{_` is no problem, but it’s the reverse of this that I’m looking for.

I feel like I might be heading in the wrong direction with a lookup approach like this. Am I missing something more simple here?

Comment: Why, it is correct. Match, capture and skip.

Comment: Granted - but the negative lookbehind captures the ones I want. However it wont work in IE and Firefox.

Comment: What are you matching those strings for? Extracting or replacing?

Comment: replacing - I want to run a replacement on the `{{` occurrences that are not preceded by a `<em>` tag already

Comment: Why not look ahead for the closing tag? `/{{[^}]*?}}(?!<\/em>)/g`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex negative lookbehind not valid in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142364/regex-negative-lookbehind-not-valid-in-javascript)

Comment: @arius the question your linking to specifically asks WHY that example does not work in Plunker. I know why my example of a negative look behind doesn't work - I'm looking to secure possible examples of how I might approach my quandary from another angle.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's a really good idea. Gives me a direction to work with

Comment: @petehotchkiss Doesn't the answer provided in the other thread answer your question ?

Comment: @Arius I'm afraid not - it's related - but the crux of the question is cognitively somewhat different. That is specifically asking "why" - I'm asking "how" I can take an alternative approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead look ahead for the closing tag: `/{{[^}]*?}}(?!<\/em>)/g`

```js
let test = "The quick brown {{ fox }} jumped over the lazy <em>{{ dog }}</em> asdfafds {{ fox }} asdf asdf asdf sdfasdfsdf <em>{{ dog }}</em>";
console.log("input: " + test);
console.log("output: " + test.replace(/({{[^}]*?}})(?!<\/em>)/g, "<em>$1</em>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to access whatever is inside those `{{ }}` and wrap it in a `<em>` tag.

You can use the RegEx [`([^>]){{(.*?)}}`](https://regex101.com/r/TVFwlP/2)

And replace with `$1<em>$2</em>`

- `([^>])` makes sure the preceding char isn't a `>`
- `{{(.*?)}}` matches anything inside `{{ }}`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/TVFwlP/2)

Comment: That almost gets there - only slight snag in it is it will match the _e_ in `space{{ here }}`

@Joseph Marikle's example above looks to have nailed it

Comment: @petehotchkiss It will, but it also replaces it back with `$1`

Answer (score 0):

You may match any `<em>` contents using `<em>[\s\S]*?<\/em>` regex and then match the `{{...}}` substrings with `{{[\s\S]*?}}` pattern in all other contexts, capture either of them and use custom logic in the callback method:

```js
console.log(
  "The quick brown {{ fox }} jumped over the lazy <em>{{ dog }}</em>"
          .replace(/<em>[\s\S]*?<\/em>|({{[\s\S]*?}})/g, function ($0,$1) {
                 return $1 ? '<em>' + $1 + '</em>' : $0;
            })
);
```

With `$1 ?`, we check if Group 1 matched, and if yes, the value is wrapped with `<em>` tags, else, it is just pasted back with `$0` (the whole match).