# Regex lookahead AND lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-lookarounds

I want to replace all `®` signs on my website to an `<sup>®</sup>` with JavaScript. But I have to care that I only replace them if there is no sup surrounding them already (maybe from CMS users).

I already tried the following but it does not work fine.

`html.replace(/(?<!<sup>.{0,})®(?!.{0,}<\/sup>)/g, "<sup>&reg;</sup>")`

It does only care for the `</sup>` Tag and does not work in Safari cause of an "invalid group specifier name". Maybe someone here can help me with this.

Comment: You need [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641432/3832970) that was [expanded here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143111/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex replace with an alternation and callback:

```js
var input = "Hello ® and also <sup>®</sup>";
var output = input.replace(/<sup>®<\/sup>|®/g, (x) => x === "<sup>®</sup>" ? x : "<sup>®</sup>");
console.log(output);
```

The alternation logic first eagerly attempts to find `<sup>®</sup>` occurrences.  That failing, it also tries to find any other `®` occurrence.  Then, in the callback, we wrap with `<sup>` tags only if not already wrapped.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Super easy solution for my problem.